# Swift : UILabel perform animation for color

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uilabel

There are few labels on my dashboard. I want to perform animation of color for few seconds.

**Requirement :** When label controls is touched by user it should display white color from centre point of label and should flow through the dimension of label thereafter it should regain to its original color.

**For Eg. :** When you tap numeric pad in screen-lock state. It highlights that button is pressed by showing white coloured button for fraction of second.

How can this be achieved in Swift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code solved my problem :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let objKeypadCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! KeypadCollectionViewCell
        objKeypadCollectionViewCell.lblNumber.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        objKeypadCollectionViewCell.lblNumber.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        objKeypadCollectionViewCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor

        let seconds = 0.15
        let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
        let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

        dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.lblNumber.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.lblNumber.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
            objKeypadCollectionViewCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        })

     . . .    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a UILabel, use a UIButton. It behaves exactly the way you want — namely, like a button. The text in a UIButton *is* actually a UILabel, so you lose nothing by using a button instead of a label, and you gain button behavior, which is what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            self.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
 }, completion: nil)

@IBAction func buttonReleased(sender : UIButton){
            self.button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
 }
```

Connect the buttonReleased func with Touch Down Sent Event from storyboard ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a658N.png)).
I hope this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty cool effect and something I've used in the past. I think this is what you are looking for. Hope it help! :

https://github.com/zoonooz/ZFRippleButton